# The meaning of 'stop-start' in this phrase

Tags: meaning

> This year it has been far more ***stop-start***, from the high of the Champions League games against Real Madrid and their 4-1 win over Liverpool, to performanaces that have been so poor, they have been pretty shocking.

Comment: Like stop-and-go traffic.

Comment: 'On and off' is the same metaphor, and perhaps more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means **intermittent**, or **sporadic**.  @hot-licks' example is good.